# How to signal/notify super-controller of change in sub-controller?

Tags: scala, javafx, architecture, signals-slots, scalafx

In JavaFX, how do you model the following:

I show a List of Customers in a Scene. On the left side there is a table on the right side (*contentPane*) the currently select customer's details are shown.

(Relevant part of) Main-Controller:

```
@jfxf.FXML
protected def newButtonPressed(): Unit =
{
    contentPane.getChildren.clear
    contentPane.getChildren.add(FXMLLoader.load(GUILoader.load("customers/form.fxml")))
}
```

There is a Button to add a new Customer. Upon clicking this button instead of opening a Popup, I replace the "details"-part of the scene and add a form there.

Now for this form (designed - like the rest of the GUI - in the SceneBuilder and saved as .fxml) I use another controller.

```
class Form extends Main with jfxf.Initializable
{
    @jfxf.FXML
    private var foreNameTextField: jfxsc.TextField = _
    @jfxf.FXML
    private var lastNameTextField: jfxsc.TextField = _
    @jfxf.FXML
    private var ageTextField: jfxsc.TextField = _

    override def initialize(url: URL, resourceBundle: ResourceBundle): Unit =
    {

    }

    @jfxf.FXML
    protected def ok(): Unit =
    {
        // TODO validation
        val newPerson = new Person(-1, foreNameTextField.getText, lastNameTextField.getText, ageTextField.getText.toInt)
       // Save to DB
       // Close whole form
    }
}
```

When I'm done with filling in a new customer's detail I click on another button (that calls ok()) and save it to a database.

What I want to do now is close the form and replace it with the detail-form.

Something like calling a protected method in the main-controller like:

```
protected def clearDetails(): Unit =
{
   contentPane.getChildren.clear
   contentPane.getChildren.add(savedOldDetails)
}
```

won't work of course. (Will throw a runtime-exception because there is no contentpane in the sub/form-controller (even if I make it protected)

In Qt (C++) I'd use signals/slots and connect them accordingly.

Seems like in JavaFX there is nothing the like. How am I supposed to share such information?

Do I need to create a "super-controller" for the contentPane?

Answer (score 0):

(I don't know Scala, so I'll write this in Java, hope that is ok).

You can define an observable property in the `Form` controller, and observe it when you load the form from the main controller:

```
public class Form implements Initializable {

    private final ObjectProperty<Person> person = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(null);

    public ObjectProperty<Person> personProperty() {
        return person ;
    }

    public final Person getPerson() {
        return personProperty().get();
    }

    public final void setPerson(Person person) {
        personProperty().set(person);
    }

    // ... code you had before...

    @FXML
    protected void ok() {
        Person person = new Person(-1, foreNameTextField.getText(), lastNameTextField.getText(), ageTextField.getText());
        // save to DB...
        personProperty().set(person);
    }
}
```

Now in your main controller, load the form as follows:

```
@FXML
protected void newButtonPressed() {
    contentPane.getChildren().clear();
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("customers/form.fxml"));
    Parent form = loader.load();
    Form formController = loader.getController();
    formController.personProperty().addListener((obs, oldPerson, newPerson) {
        if (newPerson != null) {
            // clear form, etc, e.g.
            clearDetails();
        }
    });
    contentPane.getChildren().add(form);
}
```